# How To apply Multiple Class To Multiple Div In jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

All images will be echo with a same class. this is my php code which echo the images

```
echo '<img class="my_image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['image']) . '">';
```

All images which will be echo have same class **my_image** now i have 4 different classes for animation **cl0,cl1,cl2,cl3**

The total number of div which will be echo through php code is 20 now i want to apply these four classes to all these 20 images in an ascending order

```
var colors = ["cl1","cl2","cl3","cl4"];


        var i = 0;
        $(".my_image").each(function(){
            $(this).addClass(colors[i]);
            if(i == colors.length-1)
            {
                i = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;    
            }
        });
    });
```

which is not working i have used a var colors in which i have tried to define four classes and now i want to echo through a loop all these four classes should be applied to 20 images like

```
cl0 should be applied to image 1
cl1 should be applied to image 2
cl2 should be applied to image 3
cl3 should be applied to image 4
cl0 should be applied to image 5
cl1 should be applied to image 6
```

Which is not working

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't set the cl-x classes in php?

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/qg85ypg0/). Be sure you're running your code **after** the elements exist. The best way to do that is to put your code in a `script` tag at the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Side note: When looping like that, you can update `i` much more simply: `i = (i + 1) % colors.length;`

Comment: And actually, you don't even need `i`, `each` gives you an index you can use, as the first argument. Just use it like this: `colors[index % colors.length]`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you please ellaborate the code further i have explained what i am actually trying to doo but you are making very confusing

Comment: @nullvoid: Again: Your code works, that link is to a jsFiddle which is just a copy of your code, working. So we can't answer your question, because you've said it isn't working, but it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the images and use the index of the image and modulo 4, like this

```js
var colors = ["cl1","cl2","cl3","cl4"];
$(".my_image").each(function(i, el){
  $(el).addClass(colors[i % 4]);
});
```

```css
.cl1 {
  color: red;
}
.cl2{
  color: green;
}
.cl3 {
  color: blue;
}
.cl4{
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="my_image">1</p>
<p class="my_image">2</p>
<p class="my_image">3</p>
<p class="my_image">4</p>
<p class="my_image">5</p>
<p class="my_image">6</p>
<p class="my_image">7</p>
<p class="my_image">8</p>
<p class="my_image">9</p>
<p class="my_image">10</p>
```

Comment: The OP's code works, so this really should be a comment. (And in fact, it's a comment I made a couple of minutes ago. :-) )